# Karma Error: Expected one matching request for criteria found 2 requests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, jasmin

Hi I am trying to write a unit test case for subscribe method of a controller.

I am getting the below error for the second test case

```
Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2", found 2 requests.
    at HttpClientTestingBackend.expectOne (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2015/http/testing.mjs:279:19)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/admin/employee/employee.component.spec.ts:73:26)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:372:1)
```

Employee.controller.ts

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeeService } from 'src/app/Service/employee.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
  public employeeDetails:any[] = [];
  public newEmployee:any = {
   name:"",
    job:""
  }

  constructor(public employee:EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEmployeeList();
  }
  

  getEmployeeList(){
    this.employee.getEmployeeList().subscribe(
      data=>{
        this.employeeDetails = data.data;
        console.log(data);
      },
      error=>{
        console.log(error);
      }
    )

  }

  AddNewEmployee(){
    this.employeeDetails.push(this.newEmployee);
  }
  
  DeleteEmployee(id:Number){
    this.employee.deleteEmp(id).subscribe(
      data=>{
        console.log(data);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Employee.controller.spec.ts

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

import { EmployeeComponent } from './employee.component';
import { EmployeeService } from 'src/app/Service/employee.service';

describe('EmployeeComponent', () => {
  let component: EmployeeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EmployeeComponent>;
  let service: EmployeeService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  const emp = {
    data: [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Michael",
        "last_name": "Lawson",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Lindsay",
        "last_name": "Ferguson",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/8-image.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "email": "tobias.funke@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Tobias",
        "last_name": "Funke",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/9-image.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [EmployeeComponent],
      providers: [EmployeeService]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EmployeeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    service = TestBed.inject(EmployeeService);
    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should call ngonInit method', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'ngOnInit').and.callThrough();
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.ngOnInit).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should return list of employees', () => {
    service.getEmployeeList().subscribe((data) => {
      expect(data).toEqual(emp.data);
    })

    const req = httpMock.expectOne('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2');
    expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
    req.flush(emp.data);
    httpMock.verify();
  })

});
```

Can somebody help me by letting me know what mistake I am making here and what is the meaning of the error Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: [https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2"](https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2%22), found 2 requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you show the `ngOnInit`? I bet the `ngOnInit` does `getEmployeeList` as well and you do `service.getEmployeeList` in the test also meaning there are two API calls where you are saying there is one (`httpMock.expectOne(`.

To fix it, I would change the 2nd test to:

```
it('should return list of employees', fakeAsync(() => {
    const req = httpMock.expectOne('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2');
    expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
    req.flush(emp.data);

    // Add an expect on the component here (something like this).
    // Use fakeAsync/tick to ensure the subscribe of the ngOnInit
    // completed before our assertion.
    tick();
    expect(component.employees).toEqual(emp.data);
    
    httpMock.verify();
  }))
```

Comment: Updated the controller code.

Does ngOnInit also get called while running this test case?

Comment: Yes, so you can assert `component.employeeDetails`. `ngOnInit` does get called running this test case because the first `fixture.detectChanges();` you call in the test, calls `ngOnInit()`.